# Fetch updated data from MySQL to excel

Tags: mysql, excel

Is there any way to fetch the data from MySQL to EXCEL. I tried doing it by a standard way(ODBC).

But is there any way by which all the tables data can be fetched into excel tables at once so that I can draw charts using them. If any data is added in MySQL the updated data should be reflected in Excel when I open it next time and graph should be updated.

Any way to do that?

Comment: While Surfing Net I came across this link, http://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/excel-to-mysql/, I think this will totally do what ever you want and you will need not code anything at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to write code for that.
If u are using .Net then you can directly export file in the form of excel. But if u r using java then u need to write code for that. u need to use **jxl.jar** .

hint for that is given in URL which is given below.

http://javamix.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/inserting-data-into-excel-sheet-using-jexcel-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can export your data from MySQL as Excel using any of the MySQL GUI tools like [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php), [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). I use SQLyog, here is the screen shot attached, where it can be done very easily.

But I fear, there is any direct and simple way to update data in Excel when one changes in MySQL.

Hope this helps.
[image: Screenshot]